# Why do I see strange behaviour when echo of a variable inside quotes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a Windows batch file that will detect the version of Visual Studio installed and then run an appropriate script to setup compilation on the command line, using cmd.exe on Windows 7.

If I use echo like this:

```
echo "calling %VSPATH%"
```

then I get error:

```
\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.
```

But without the quotes, like this

```
echo calling %VSPATH%
```

then no error.

And in other parts of the script I am echoing variables using quotes seemingly without error.

Here is the full script, setup.bat:

```
@echo off

if defined VS160COMNTOOLS (
  echo "Using VS2019 path: %VS160COMNTOOLS%"
  set VSPATH="%VS160COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
) else (
  if defined VS150COMNTOOLS (
    echo "Using VS2017 path: %VS150COMNTOOLS%"
    set VSPATH="%VS150COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
  ) else (
    if defined VS140COMNTOOLS (
      echo "Using VS2015 path: %VS140COMNTOOLS%"
      set VSPATH="%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
    ) else (
      if defined VS120COMNTOOLS (
        echo "Using VS2013 path: %VS120COMNTOOLS%"
        set VSPATH="%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
      ) else (
        if defined VS110COMNTOOLS (
          echo "Using VS2012 path: %VS110COMNTOOLS%"
          set VSPATH="%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

if defined VSPATH (
  REM "error on below line if enclose in quotes???"
  echo calling %VSPATH%
  REM call %VSPATH%
) else (
  echo "!!!No VSXXXCOMNTOOLS environment variable set!!!"
  echo "If you have installed Visual Studio, please set the VSXXXCOMNTOOLS variable and rerun this script"
)
```

To reproduce the behaviour I am experiencing, you can try:

```
set VS160COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\
setup.bat
```

Comment: What does `vspath` contain when this occurs? Try using `set vspath` to display it

Comment: Please do not use doublequotes in the variable content, doublequote the variable when you use it, if needed. Currently you are using ```set var="string"```. When you do that, obviously ```echo "calling %var%"``` would pre-expand to ```echo "calling "string""``` and the doublequotes would confuse the parser, _(especially if there's a poison character in that string)_. Example: ```Echo "calling "hello & goodbye""```. If you used the recommended ```set "var=string"``` and ```echo "calling %var%"```, it would pre-expand to ```echo "calling hello & goodbye"``` and do exactly what you wanted of it.

Comment: @Compo I wasn't aware of set "var=string with spaces" - that does seem to fix the problem